# Publish to Azure did not create all SQL tables

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core

I created an ASP.NET Core MVC code first project.
All works fine on LocalHost

After publishing it to Azure, most tables created fine, in some tables all the columns were not created and one table was not created at all.

Could it be that I deleted some of the migration files while still developing on LocalHost? Or does the Publish to Azure process create a new complete Migration?

How do I now get the latest version of my database, as I have on LocalHost, migrated to Azure?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to publish your application to Azure and the process of doing so to change the migration files generated by entity framework. Note that you need to create the database in Azure first then publish your web app.

Comment: Hi Andi. Are the migration files generated at the point of publishing?  I did not create the database in Azure 1st  and then publish, it created the database during the publishing process

Comment: Is there a way to redo the migration to Azure?

Answer (score 0):

My Db, Migration files and ModelSnapShot somehow went out of sync. I think I edited some migration files at some point.

Got it fixed in dev by deleting all migration files, dropping the db and then adding the migration again.